# Combine different queries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I've got some accounting app which allows to create documents and add some positions to it ( lines/rows ).
Here's controller to get those rows of particular document:

```
public JsonResult GetIncDocDetails(long id, int pagesize, int pagenum)
    {   
        var dbResult = db.fooIncDocDetail.Where(d => d.DocumentID == id).Where(d => d.RecordStatusID != 2).Include(f => f.fooFood).
                             OrderBy(d => d.Date).
                             Select(s => new
                             {
                                 s.IncDocDetailID,
                                 s.FoodID,
                                 s.MeasureUnit,
                                 s.Amount,
                                 s.Price,
                                 s.VATRate,         
                                 s.Excise,
                                 s.DocumentID,
                                 s.UserID,
                                 s.RecordDate,             
                                 s.RecordStatusID,
                                 s.Date,
                                 s.FoodName,
                                 s.DetailNumber,
                                 fooFoodName = s.fooFood.Name
                             }).Skip(pagesize * pagenum).Take(pagesize);

        return Json(dbResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

So I want to get some more information by this controller such as:

1. Total sum of all rows of this particular document:

   ```
   Summa = db.fooIncDocDetail.Where(d => d.DocumentID == id).
                       Where(d => d.RecordStatusID == 1).
                       Sum(a => (decimal?)(a.Amount* a.Price)) ?? 0;
   ```
2. Total count of all rows of this particular document:

   ```
   Total = db.fooIncDocDetail.Where(d => d.DocumentID == id).
                       Where(d => d.RecordStatusID != 2)
                       .Count()
   ```
3. Properties of this particular document:

   ```
   Document = db.fooDocument.Where(d => d.DocumentID == id).
                                           Select(d => new
                                           {
                                               d.DocumentID,
                                               d.DocDate,
                                               d.RegNumber,
                                               d.UserID,
                                               d.RecordDate,
                                               d.RecordStatusID,
                                               d.RegistrationDate,
                                               d.Number,
                                               d.Description,
                                               d.ObjectID,
                                               d.DocumentTypeID,
                                               d.ContragentName,
                                               DocumentTypeName = d.fooDocumentType.Name
                                           })
   ```

But how can I combine all that in just one LINQ query, which I wrote first? Thanks

Comment: I would not try to merge all these queries into one, instead I would create a parametrized stored procedure in the DB and use that. This will probably create the least overhead as you only have to send one query and get all the answers.

Comment: Aren't `fooDocument` and `fooInDocDetail` related? Shouldn't there be a relation between them so you could load all related entities with an `.Include()`? Since you want all the details, it wouldn't make *all* that much sense to perform the aggregations in the database. Once you have the data on the client, you can perform any kind of aggregation you want in them.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can embed all the detail queries into the last query `Select` by projecting them into properties of anonymous or specifically created type, so the original, (1) and (2) become subqueries of (3). Just change the `d` variable to avoid clash, for instance:

```
// The original query. Must be declared here and put into variable
// to avoid exception due to `Skip` / `Take` subquery processing EF bug
// It still will be executed as part of the other query
var details = ...;

var result = db.fooDocument
    .Where(d => d.DocumentID == id).
    .Select(doc => new
    {
        Document = new
        {
            doc.DocumentID,
            doc.DocDate,
            doc.RegNumber,
            doc.UserID,
            doc.RecordDate,
            doc.RecordStatusID,
            doc.RegistrationDate,
            doc.Number,
            doc.Description,
            doc.ObjectID,
            doc.DocumentTypeID,
            doc.ContragentName,
            DocumentTypeName = doc.fooDocumentType.Name
        },
        Summa = ...,
        Total = ...,
        Details = details
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks, Ivan, please, check this out:

Comment: // request Details = 
    Details = doc.fooIncDocDetail.Where(f => f.RecordStatusID != 2).
                            OrderBy(f => f.Date).
                            Select(detail => new
                            {
                                // some detail properties                                
                            }).
                                            Skip(pagesize * pagenum).Take(pagesize)
I got this exception there: Count must be a DbConstantExpression or a DbParameterReferenceExpression

Comment: Then there is no other choice than making `Details` part separate. I had some complaints about combining it with the other parts anyway because even if it worked, it would create a big union query with many fields unused in master and many unused in the detail record of the returned single result set. So, exclude Details from the answer and execute 2 queries, which I guess is still better than 4 :)

Comment: But since in this particular case the details query has no correlation with the parent query, it could be put into variable outside the main query and used inside, which fixes the exception - see the update.